# Configuring Laravel 4 with AWS Elasticache Memcached

Tags: php, caching, amazon-ec2, memcached, amazon-elasticache

I have Amazon Elasticache Memcached node (just one)
I have a webserver in the same region.

Cache subnet group VPC ID is the same as EC2 instance's, the permissions are set properly from AWS perspective.

In laravel in config/cache.php

```
'driver' => 'memcached',
```

and

```
'memcached' => array(
        array('host' => 'xxxxx.xxxx.xxx.xxxx.cache.amazonaws.com', 'port' => 11211, 'weight' => 100),
),
```

However, Cache::has('key') and Cache::add('key'); do not work.

Do I need a special package for Laravel to work with AWS Elasticache? I only have one node and do not need auto-discovery.

Thanks

P.S. Is there way to get a log for AWS Elasticache? or laravel? logs directory is *empty*

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use the elasticache-laravel package, available here: https://github.com/atyagi/elasticache-laravel

Or conversely, check out this post: http://blog.hapnic.com/2013/09/11/Laravel-4-and-ElastiCache/

For your PS: Elasticache logs can be accessed this way:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/UserGuide/ManagingEvents.html

Your Laravel logs should be in `app/storage/logs` - if there's nothing in there, check the permissions of the `storage` directory and make sure it's writeable by the web server. Barring that,  check the default error log location for your web server (such as `/var/log/httpd/error_log`), as defined by your server configuration.

Comment: Thanks for the link (github), I did try hapnic's suggestion, it didn't seeem to work, but I haven't really messed with it. 

The logs are working (other things get logged), I was expecting Cache errors, but I guess broken cache driver doesn't output errors by default.

Comment: Let me know how you make out. I'll try to help if the github package doesn't work for you.

Comment: I am trying to use this package as well and face a problem I don't really understand as the Cache is clearly not working after I set it up. I submitted an issue on https://github.com/atyagi/elasticache-laravel/issues/2 to request some help to the author